# Entity Framework returns every table from Azure DB instead of one

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, entity-framework, azure

I'm building a Web Api using ASP.NET and an existing Azure DB. I'm running into an issue with entity framework and the Azure DB. I've used ADO.NET to generate all of the model classes from the database with the code-first version..

This is a snippet of my dbcontext that was generated with ADO.NET:

```
public IntelliMonDbContext()
            : base("name=IntelliMonDbContext")
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<C__MigrationHistory> C__MigrationHistory { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; }
```

After all of the dbset properties there is a method called OnModelCreating. I'm not really sure what that one does but since it was generated I don't think this is where my method lies.

My problem is, that in my DevicesController I'm trying to return a list of all of my devices in JSON-format, but instead it returns all of the tables in my Azure DB. I've tried trying to query for other tables in the db instead of Devices, but I get the exact same result. Even when I try requesting with a specific device-id I get all of the tables in one JSON-object.

```
// GET: api/Devices
        public IEnumerable<Device> GetDevices()
        {
            return db.Devices.ToList();
        }
```

I've worked with lokal Db's and entity-framework before and I have never had any issues. I don't understand how the query above can give me all of the tables in the DB in one JSON-object. Have I missed a cruicial step when generating the models using ADO.NET? What might be the issue here? I've tried my best searching for similar posts but I can't find anything that matches, since this feels like it's such a simple thing that should not go wrong.

If it's needed I'll provide more information.

Comment: Sounds like eager loading to me.

Comment: Try taking virtual off the DbSets unless you are doing something advanced or mocking.

Comment: I tried it, but my result is exactly the same.. Any other suggestions? I can't understand what the issue is. I've worked with local dbs so many times and have not had an issue like this.

Comment: @Maarten Thank you for your answer. Any suggestions on what I should do to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the ICollections inside of the objects that was doing this. I only removed virtual from the properties as suggested by another user, but I missed the ICollections that was auto generated by ADO.NET.

Thank you for the help.